# Statistics not showing in Open x - PEAR error

Tags: openx

On an older website I'm still using Open X 2.8 for my banner advertisements. I'm not in the position right now to change this to another banner server.

My problem is that since a week or so the statistics have stopped working. I'm getting the following errors:

```
PEAR Error 

XML_Parser: Undeclared entity error at XML input line 60:48
```

And

```
PEAR Error 

XML_Parser: Attribute redefined at XML input line 235:20
```

I don't have a clue on where I should look for the problem